# style attribute 'app:attr/cornerRadius' not found

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

i am getting compile time error from below code.

```
<style name="TextButton">
        <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
        <item name="fontFamily">@font/raleway_bold</item>
        <item name="app:backgroundTint">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="app:cornerRadius">25dp</item>
        <item name="app:rippleColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/whiteFont</item>
</style>
```

Comment: You're using `cornerRadius` twice in your style, remove this one `<item name="cornerRadius:">25dp</item>`.

Comment: still getting same error

Comment: what does `cornerRadius` attribute does ? is it for `CustomView` you're using?

Comment: i am using MaterialButton in xml.

Comment: What if you remove `<item name="app:cornerRadius">25dp</item>` ? Check if error is gone.

Comment: error gone if i remove all attribute start from "app".

Answer (score 9):

Try like this, The solution is to **NOT** specify the namespace *(app: in your case)* in the style:

```
<style name="TextButton">
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/raleway_bold</item>
    <item name="backgroundTint">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="cornerRadius">25dp</item>
    <item name="rippleColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/whiteFont</item>
</style>
```